# Unable to open pyspark in mac os

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed pyspark through pip but unable to open it. It shows following error .

> Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 24:
>   /Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh:
>   No such file or directory
>   /Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 77:
>   /Users/sonveer.narwaria//Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit:
>   No such file or directory
>   /Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec:
>   /Users/sonveer.narwaria//Users/sonveer.narwaria/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-submit:
>   cannot execute: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

You should download a full Spark distribution as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). PyPi installations of PySpark (i.e through `pip`, as you did) are suitable only for connecting with an already existing Spark cluster; from the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup your own standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version of Spark from the Apache Spark downloads page.
>
> **NOTE**: If you are using this with a Spark standalone cluster you must
>   ensure that the version (including minor version) matches or you may
>   experience odd errors