# pyspark: Could not find valid SPARK_HOME

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip

After a fresh installation of `pyspark` via  `pip install pyspark` I get the following errors:

```
> pyspark
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/Users', '/usr/local/bin']
/usr/local/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pyspark: line 77: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
> spark-shell
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/Users', '/usr/local/bin']
/usr/local/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

What is a valid `SPARK_HOME`, how do I set it, and why is there no default that works?

I've seen instructions on how to manually set the environment variable after a manual installation of spark, but I am wondering how to set it in this case after using `pip` to install `pyspark`.

I've installed only spark via `brew install apache-spark`, and the `spark-shell` that comes out of that installation works just fine out of the box. After installing pyspark after that, I get the messages above. Confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to open pyspark in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636042/unable-to-open-pyspark-in-mac-os)

Comment: @user8371915 Why is this a duplicate given that the error messages are entirely different?

Comment: PyPi version is not designed to be a complete Spark installation.  It is only a development helper.

Comment: @user8371915 Thanks, that's an important info. Still, one would not expect it to break the existing spark installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> brew install apache-spark
```

actually already provides a working `pyspark` shell. It is not necessary to additionally

```
> pip install pyspark
```

and in fact this breaks the installation for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command if you already installed apache-pyspark through brew.

```
brew link --overwrite apache-spark
```