# Downloading PySpark onto Macbook Air

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I followed the instructions on this site and seem to be having issues when I come to calling pyspark in my terminal. I have Anaconda installed.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-get-started-with-pyspark-1adc142456ec

[Output from pyspark command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxoEM.png)

Any help/guidance would be appreciated if anyone has alternative ways to get this downloaded or know how I can fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark: Could not find valid SPARK\_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707239/pyspark-could-not-find-valid-spark-home)

Comment: Search this site for *Could not find valid SPARK_HOME* and you'll find many previous posts that have been answered.  Always do at least a basic search for the error message before posting a new question, as chances are quite good that the question has been asked and answered before.